# InvalidPluginException: UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=ml/commandermc/rtp/Main, offset=6 Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So I have been getting this error for my Java Code.
I am making a minecraft plugin for my server and every time I try to run the jar file, it will give me this error.

```
[11:11:42] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/RandomTp.jar' in folder 'plugins'
```

org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=ml/commandermc/rtp/Main, offset=6

I have no clue how to fix it. I tried Reinstalling Java and Eclipse. Changing my complier settings in Eclipse. Nothing seems to work.

Anything helps!
Thanks,
If you need more info please tell me.

Comment: That error usually means that the Java Class that you are calling is compiled against a higher version than the JVM of the calling code. You need to post more detail about the version of the JVM you are running..

Comment: I somehow managed to fix it. I have no idea how but never had Java JRE installed. Thanks though.